# Match 2 different routes with different parameters in React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a component that I'd like to match to 2 paths: `/` and `/:value`. My route looks like this:

`<Route path="/(|:value)" render={(props) => { return <MyComponent/>}}`

This above route does match `/`, but will NOT match `/:value`. If I hard code the route to:

`<Route path="/(|mypath)" render={(props) => { return <MyComponent/>}}`

it will match both `/` and `/mypath`. How can I get my route to match BOTH `/` and `/any-value-i-put-here`?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify a Route with conditional parameter like

```
<Route path="/:value?" render={(props) => { return <MyComponent {...props}/>}}
```

and it will match `/` and `/any-value`. After this you can access the param if it exists like `this.props.match.params.value`

> **P.S.** Also when you use render, make sure you pass the props to the
>   rendered component